# Android Universal Image Loader to re-load SDcard at MainActivity

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am developing a camera application with Universal Image loader(UIL).

The problem I have faced is that after taking a picture(it will be stored in sdcard), gridFragment does not refresh sdcard so a new picture does not display on there.

Any idea with it? code below. Thank you for reading it!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int CAMERA_CODE = 100;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private String[] imageurl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ File.separator;

        String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "MyCameraApp/";

       int frIndex = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constants.Extra.FRAGMENT_INDEX, 0);
        Fragment fr;
        String tag;
        int titleRes;
        tag = "hi";
        fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (fr == null) {
            fr = new ImageGridFragment();
            fr.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        }

        titleRes = R.string.app_name;
        setTitle(titleRes);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fr, tag).commit();

        ImageLoader.getInstance()
                .init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(MainActivity.this));
        imageurl = ImageGridFragment.getimages();
        //ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageurl,MainActivity.this);
    }
```

> ---

```
public class ImageGridFragment extends AbsListViewBaseFragment {

    public static final int INDEX = 1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        listView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        ((GridView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startImagePagerActivity(position);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    public static String[] getimages() {
        String[] images=new String[175];
        String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ File.separator;

        String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "MyCameraApp/";
        int counter=0;
        String name;
        File yourDir = new File(ExternalStorageDirectoryPath, "MyCameraApp/");
        for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile()){
                name = "file:///"+targetPath + f.getName().toString() ;
                images[counter]=name;
                // make something with the name
                counter++;}
        }
        return images;
    }
    public static String[] IMAGE_URLS = getimages();
    private static class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


        String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ File.separator;

        String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "MyCameraApp/";
        //private List<File> files = getListFiles(new File(targetPath));
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        private DisplayImageOptions options;

        ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_action_name)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_err)
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .build();
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return IMAGE_URLS.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                assert view != null;
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            String imgPath = targetPath+"";

            String decodedImgUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imgPath)).toString();

            ImageLoader.getInstance()
                    .displayImage(IMAGE_URLS[position], holder.imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                            holder.progressBar.setProgress(0);
                            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                            holder.progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(100.0f * current / total));
                        }
                    });

            return view;
        }
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
    }
}
```

Comment: So gridFragment does not refresh after taking a picture. Where are you telling that it has to do so?

Comment: on Mainactivity, it should refresh sdcard

Comment: I just refresh IMAGE_URLS = getimages();  Thank you, you gave me a good idea, greenapps